# Facing issue while configurating Code::Blocks

Tags: codeblocks

[image]

While I am using my Code::Blocks IDE, this message is displayed. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please include the error message in the question, as this way it can be indexed by the search engine and enable other users with the same issue to find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it means that you do not have a compiler installed on your computer (or at least not one that CodeBlocks can find)

If you download the CodeBlocks installer from 
[codeblocks-16.01mingw-setup.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/16.01/Windows/codeblocks-16.01mingw-setup.exe)
It should come with the GCC compiler :)

If you do have it installed, go to Settings>Compiler...>Toolchain Executables tab. then tell it where the respective programs are.

Or, if you want to install the compiler yourself try looking up MingwGet